# Laravel5 でregister（ユーザー登録）後の画面遷移が出来ない問題について

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravelで新規登録後にプロフィール画面に遷移させたいのですが、登録の処理は出来ているし、ChromeのデベロッパーツールでNetworkで通信を確認してもちゃんとPOSTされた後にリダイレクトしたいURLもResponseで返ってきているのですが、何故か画面は切り替わらず登録画面のままです。

プロパティのリダイレクト先も変更したのですが、原因がいくら調べてもわかりません何故なのか分かる方いらっしゃいますか。

#### 試したこと

①RegisterController.phpの記述を以下の通り変更

**変更前:**

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

**変更後:**

```
protected $redirectTo = '/mypage/profile';
```

②RegisterController.phpに下記のredirectToメソッドを作成

```
protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return route('mypage.prof');
    }
```

③Chrome以外のブラウザで試した

④vagrantとhomesteadでサーバーを立てていたので、php artisan serveの方でやってみた

⑤php artisan キャッシュクリア系のコマンドでキャッシュクリアしてみた

⑥Chromeの設定でCookieを削除

上記のことを試しても挙動が変わりませんでした。自分で調べられる限りは試してみたのですがエラーも出ていないしさっぱり原因がわかりません。他に考えうる原因はあるのでしょうか？

ちなみに下記画像のように遷移先のURLはGETでResponseがちゃんと返ってきています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

#### 関連するソースコード

**Network**

```
**register**

Request URL: http://homestead.test/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 192.168.20.10:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

**profile**

Request URL: http://homestead.test/mypage/profile
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 192.168.20.10:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/mypage/profile', 'UserController@showProf')->name('mypage.prof');
```

**UserController.php**

```
// プロフィール画面表示
    public function showProf()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('user.prof', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
```

**Router.php**

```
public function auth(array $options = [])
    {
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@showLogout')->name('logout');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        if ($options['register'] ?? true) {
            $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
            $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
        }
        $this->get('withdraw', 'Auth\RegisterController@showWithdraw')->name('withdraw');


        // Password Reset Routes...
        if ($options['reset'] ?? true) {
            $this->resetPassword();
        }

        // Email Verification Routes...
        if ($options['verify'] ?? false) {
            $this->emailVerification();
        }
    }
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/mypage/profile';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6',],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**RegistersUsers.php**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());

    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during registration.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

**register.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app2')

@section('title', '会員登録')

@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <user-register></user-register>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**UserRegister.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="l-form p-form">
        <h2 class="l-form__head p-form__head">
            新規会員登録
        </h2>

        <div class="l-form__body p-form__body">
            <div class="l-form-conteiner">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="l-form__label p-form__label">メールアドレス</label>
                    <span class="label-require">必須</span>
                    <input id="email" class="l-form__input p-form__input" :class="{ hasErr: errors.email }" type="text" v-model="email" placeholder="PC・携帯どちらでも可">
                    <div class="area-msg">
                        {{ errors.email }}
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="l-form__label p-form__label">パスワード</label>
                    <span class="label-require">必須</span>
                    <input id="password" class="l-form__input p-form__input" :class="{ hasErr: errors.password }" type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="6文字以上の半角英数字">
                    <div class="area-msg">
                        {{ errors.password }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="p-btn btn-primary" @click="register">登録する</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                email: '',
                password: '',
                errors: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            register: function () {

                this.errors = {};

                var self = this;
                var url = '/register';
                var params = {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                };
                axios.post(url, params)
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.email = '';
                    self.password = '';
                })
                .catch(function (error) {

                    var responseErrors = error.response.data.errors;
                    var errors = {};

                    for(var key in responseErrors) {

                        errors[key] = responseErrors[key][0];

                    }

                    self.errors = errors;
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequestの302のハンドリングをしていないようですけど、それは書き忘れですかね？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。すみません初学者で、そのあたりまだよく理解できていないのですが、もう少し詳しく教えていただけますでしょうか？
302のハンドリングは書き忘れではなく、分からないと言った方が正しいです、すみません。

Answer (score 2):

ブラウザからのアクセスではなくて
XMLHttpRequestの場合は、302リダイレクトを実施してもXMLHttpRequestでは何も転送されません。
XMLHttpRequestは画面の遷移をせずにHTTPをリクエストを送ることが目的なので、自分たちで転送する必要があります。

どのように修正するかはいくつか方法がありますが
このあたりはアプリの仕様を考えてにどちらが良いかを考えてみると良いと思います。

・Ajaxではなくて普通にHTMLを利用してFormでPOSTする
・axiosの制御を確認して302をキャッチして転送させる
・転送を302リダイレクトでやることをやめる

個人的には
・転送を302リダイレクトでやることをやめる
ほうがいいかなと思います。
というのもおそらくregisterメソッドはあくまで新規登録だけの機能にして
転送はクライアント側に委ねてしまってはいかがでしょうか？
API的にもそれがシンプルで機能の棲み分けが出来ています

具体的に言えば
RegisterController.php
ではリダイレクトをやめる

```
return $this->registered($request, $user)
    ?: $this->redirectPath();//200が返せればレスポンスは何でもいいと思います。OKでも、転送先のURLでも。
```

UserRegister.vue

```
            .then(function (response) {
                self.email = '';
                self.password = '';
                //ここは成功しているとみなして
                location.href = "転送先URL";//レクエストごとに転送先が違うならレスポンスに含めてしまってもいいでしょうね。固定ならベタ書きでも。
            })
```

といった感じでしょうか？
※すいません。手元にLaravelの環境がなかったので多分通らないです。実装のイメージだと認識していただき適宜書き換えて実装してください。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、axios内にlocation.hrefで遷移先のURLを記載したところちゃんと画面遷移させることができました。めちゃくちゃ悩んでたので本当に助かりました。回答いただきありがとうございました！